# Wicket Page constructor getting called twice

Tags: wicket

I am using wicket 1.4.17 and IE8. I am facing an issue where the HomePage constructor is being called twice. I read few other threads that this is due to  tag. I have taken care of this image tag, but still seeing the issue.

Please suggest how can this be resolved.

Please provide your thoughts on this issue. I have a url parameter which I needs to be passed on further from my home page. however as my home page constructor is being called twice I am not able to read the url parameter (second call to constructor does not has any parameters)

Comment: I encountered this too in Wicket 1.4, so I moved my affected code away from the page constructor. I have not checked whether the latest stable release of Wicket, 1.5.7, does this too, since I have already bypassed this issue.

Comment: thanks Ian for your inputs. I need to read a url parameter inside the home page constructor, i do it in the first iteration. But then again the second time it would be called, there would be no URL parameter available. how can i get the value of the parameter in the second call? I tried using getting through : RequestParameters rp = RequestCycle.get().getProcessor().getRequestCodingStrategy().decode(request); But no success so far.

Comment: so you say that the request is generated two times or that the page is being instantiated two times? Maybe the page class is being instantiated stateless with pageparameters and while rendering the page is having a redirect trying to get stateful, while not being in the sessions pagemap, the page is being instantiated a second time with default constructor. just guessing... try to find out what wicket is exaclty doing here, try out different renderstrategies this.getRequestCycleSettings().setRenderStrategy(RenderStrategy.ONE_PASS_RENDER);

Comment: page is being instantiated two times. where should i set this.getRequestCycleSettings().setRenderStrategy(RenderStrategy.ONE_PASS_RENDER)‌​; ?

Comment: Hi Mar, request you to please respond. I need to submit this fix tomorrow

Comment: i tried using getRequestCycleSettings().setRenderStrategy(IRequestCycleSettings.ONE_PASS_RENDER); and few other options here. However no success so far, page constructor is still being called twice

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have already tried placing in your `WebApplication`:

```
@Override
protected void init()
{
  super.init();
  ...
  getRequestCycleSettings().setRenderStrategy(
   org.apache.wicket.settings.IRequestCycleSettings.RenderStrategy.ONE_PASS_RENDER);
}
```

I am looking at the same problem as you once again, since I now need to have a page URL visited via a POST with processing to be made on the same web request, not waiting for the user to click an "OK" button, which I use for an E-mail address validation page.

**Update**
Please see the posts for the Wicket Users forum on Nabble "Wicket Page constructor getting called twice" at

http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Wicket-Page-constructor-getting-called-twice-tp4650225.html

for a tip to assist your debugging and location of the problem.

I hope that this helps.